# How to click available button which refuses the click?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm working on automation of one website. My problem is that the button which is visible in my selenium (simply prints out) stopped working after recent update. Eventho I can see it, I cannot click it. I've noticed that it has started to have dynamic id selector, but class stays stable. What that can be ? Is there any other way to click it ?

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div class="pull-left middle-col-4">
            <!---->
        </div>
        <div class="pull-left middle-col-4">
            <!---->
        </div>
    </div>
    <button tabindex="-1" id="exit-button-ZpyYaHCdmZ5jnmaamGhjaJjFcsVrmJOUcZWVaZlsaGlolpOaZg" class="btn btn-inverse btn-large pull-right">Wyjście</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please provide your HTML DOM structure and explain which button is visible ? would be great if you tell what are you trying to achieve. If dynamic id's are present then use selenium contains method to identify your elements or else you can use class locator to identify your element if it's stable as per your comment and then perform click on it.

Comment: @Rock edited. The id is changable and class remains stable. I need to click it. This selector worked before the update and is still visible as printed element so must be valid.

Comment: Please show an example of your selenium code and describe what happens when you run it. If you get any errors, be sure to show those.

Answer (score 0):

**Please find below solution to click exit button if id is dynamic**

**1. Xpath and contains method**

```
button=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Wyjście')]")
button.click()
```

**2. Class name**

```
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("btn btn-inverse btn-large pull-right")
element.click()
```

Comment: please accept and up vote the answer if your issue is resolved

Comment: still the same. As I mentioned, button is visible but selenium does not click on it. It's been kinda secured.

Comment: @sinusoida What do you mean by "selenium does not click on it"? What happens?

Comment: @sinusoida please your site if possible?

Answer (score 0):

To Click on the button induce `WebDriverWait` and `element_to_be_clickable`() And following locator strategy.

**By Css Selector:**

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button.btn.btn-inverse.btn-large.pull-right"))).click()
```

**By Xpath:**

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@class='btn btn-inverse btn-large pull-right' and starts-with(@id,'exit-button-')][text()='Wyjście']"))).click()
```

You need to import followings to execute above code.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```